# How to use variable name as validation for link in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a web page in which teacher can create tests for students.  This .js file collects all the tests from the server and displays them in a navigation bar. All tests are stored as JSON data. I am using a generic HTML address: "dotest.html". The problem is that I have no working validation to get a certain test. Let us say that one of the tests has the name "Java". Is it possible to create a function, that only links to this specific test which have the same variable name as the "item.testname" (Java) which are displayed in the navigation bar?

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/getTest/', showTodo);

  function showTodo(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, item) {
      $(".studentlink").append('<li><a  href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/dotest.html">' + item.testName + '</a></li>');

    });
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means certain that I completely understood what you are looking for, but if you want to limit you choice of links in the navigation bar by checking them against a white-list then the following might be helpful:

```
function showTodo(data) {
  var valid={'java':1,'php':1,'c++':1}; // object contains the "allowed" entries
  $.each(data, function(key, item) {
    if (item.testName.toLowerCase() in valid)
      $(".studentlink").append('<li><a  href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/dotest.html">' + item.testName + '</a></li>');
  });
}
```

`valid` is an object that acts as a white-list: `item.testName` will only appear as a link if it is also a key in this object.